# Formatting ifconfig using sed/awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk, ifconfig

I'm using `ifconfig` on OpenSUSE. When I run `ifconfig eth0` I get

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr CE:FD:75:DF:A5:6D
      inet addr:172.16.4.177  Bcast:172.16.5.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::adfd:75ef:fedf:v56d/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:11812456 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7000495 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:2591436376 (2471.3 Mb)  TX bytes:9196901478 (8770.8 Mb)
```

I'm looking to format this so each parameter gets returned on a new line using `sed` or `awk` e.g.:

```
   eth0  
         Link encap:Ethernet
         HWaddr CE:FD:75:DF:A5:6D
         inet addr:172.16.4.177  
         Bcast:172.16.5.255  
         Mask:255.255.254.0
         inet6 addr: fe80::adfd:75ef:fedf:v56d/64 
         Scope:Link
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  
         Metric:1
         RX packets:11812456 
         errors:0 
         dropped:2
         overruns:0 
         frame:0
         TX packets:7000495 
         errors:0
         dropped:0 
         overruns:0 
         carrier:0
         collisions:0
         txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:2591436376 (2471.3 Mb)
         TX bytes:9196901478 (8770.8 Mb)
```

I've tried `ifconfig eth0 | sed 's/   /\r/'` but that doesn't seem to split on the double space.

Comment: `sed 's/ \+/\n\t/g'` is not satisfy?

Comment: @Costas :Yeah it will do but if u look at OP's question carefully  he wants key value pair in a single line that is `Link encap:Ethernet`

Comment: @Thushi Sorry, server is strip second space in script while copying: `sed 's/  \+/\n\t/g'`

Comment: Note that `\r`? is just a carriage return. It won't throw a newline, it'll just send the cursor back to the start of the line. That _can_ be handy though, eg `for((i=0;i<=250;i+=5));do printf "\r%3d " "$i";sleep .1;done;echo`

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated - it hasn't seen a linux release in more than a decade. Stop using it. Use `ip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with

```
sed 's/\(:[^: ]\+\) \([^(]\)/\1\n\2/g;s/\()\)/\1\n/;s/^ \+//'
```

it should be close enough, and most probably can be simplified and optimized further.
The result:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet
 HWaddr CE:FD:75:DF:A5:6D
inet addr:172.16.4.177
 Bcast:172.16.5.255
 Mask:255.255.254.0
inet6 addr: fe80::adfd:75ef:fedf:v56d/64
Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500
 Metric:1
RX packets:11812456
errors:0
dropped:2
overruns:0
frame:0
TX packets:7000495
errors:0
dropped:0
overruns:0
carrier:0
collisions:0
txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:2591436376 (2471.3 Mb)
  TX bytes:9196901478 (8770.8 Mb)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script used the intermediate substitution to `=` symbol (you are free to change to any you'l want):

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/\s\+\s/=/g
/:[^=:]\+:/s/:[^=:]\+ /&=/g
s/^=/\t/
s/ *=$//
s/ *=/\n\t/g
```

So

```
ifconfig eth0 | sed -f script.above
```

outputs:

```
eth0
    Link encap:Ethernet
    HWaddr 74:2f:68:8b:b8:6e
    inet addr:192.168.1.247
    Bcast:192.168.1.255
    Mask:255.255.255.224
    inet6 addr: fe80::762f:68ff:fe8b:b86e/64
    Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST
    MTU:1500
    Metric:1
    RX packets:3128543
    errors:0
    dropped:1
    overruns:0
    frame:0
    TX packets:1346967
    errors:0
    dropped:0
    overruns:0
    carrier:0
    collisions:0
    txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:4538616348 (4.5 GB)
    TX bytes:118149772 (118.1 MB)
```